# Using SetEncryption method in OpenKM

Tags: security, encryption, openkm

I'm trying to implement encrypt our documents in OpenKM. I used setEncryption method with some cipher text and OpenKM shows me with encrypted icon. I'm confused whether its really encrypted or not.

1. Im able to download without any cipher text from OpenKM front End and API
2. Im able to preview it in OpenKM front End

How does it work and How can I make sure its really encrypted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the resolution for my problem. We don't have any option for encryption/decryption in OpenKM via API, though we have option via OpenKM front end tool.

So we should write our own mechanism for encryption/decryption and flag them as encrypted in OpenKM. I used Java Cryptographic Extension (JCE) framework and stored the encrypted file in OpenKM by flag it as encrypted and downloaded the file then did decryption

Comment: The current OpenKM cyptography tool is a JAVA web starter application what does it, at database level there's a flag what indicate when document is crypt, what can be used from API to change the status. If at the end you integrate Java Cryptographic Extension at server side this code will be welcome into the existing source code at https://github.com/openkm/document-management-system/ ,another option might be create an specific webservice as stand alone application for it, what might be distributed itself.